# Merge [spider] and [spidering]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A few hours ago, a user created the tags [spidering](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spidering) and [spider](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider). As far as I know, there is no alternative meaning of spider in the information security field (nor, for that matter, in IT).

Shouldn't these tags be merged?

Comment: In principle you are completely correct, however on consideration it is (as of right now) a useless tag to begin with (as are the other tags created for that question), so I just retagged the question (and closed it, but that is unrelated). Since those tags are now unused, they should get auto-removed by the garbage collector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question deserves an answer, but AviD already wrote all there is to say in a comment. So I will just copy paste it here:

> In principle you are completely correct, however on consideration it is (as of right now) a useless tag to begin with (as are the other tags created for that question), so I just retagged the question (and closed it, but that is unrelated). Since those tags are now unused, they should get auto-removed by the garbage collector...

Comment: I've just found out that both tags have already been removed, so I'm not sure if this question should be closed or deleted (and I don't want to ask a meta-meta-question...), but I still accepted your answer.

Comment: @A.Darwin Maybe you should ask a meta-meta-meta-question about wheather such a question would be appropriate? :-) Anyway, no need to close or delete anything, but perhaps slap a [status-completed] tag on your question?

Comment: @A.Darwin And thanks for raising the issue to begin whit! Everything we can do to avoid a tag mess is good!

Comment: Apparently, only mods can slap the [status-completed] tag. At least, that's what the error message said.